# How to get ColorBlend.js top stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-blending

I'm trying to pause the [colorBlend](http://plugins.jquery.com/content/colorblend-402) animation on a DOM object like so:

```
$('#header-container').colorBlend({action: 'stop'})
```

Nothing's happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the demos on the colorBlend site, it should be

```
$('#header-container').colorBlend("stop", "all")
```